# video in html5, content type video/x-msvideo

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am re-writing an audio & video site from way back when, and trying to utilise the new functionality built into the browser via html5. So far so good.

The video that I want to playback is of content type = video/x-msvideo, which is not supported by html5 (this I derive from various searches not bringing me to a  positive conclusion).

The video should be played back via the chrome browswer, and one way that I so far have tried that ((semi))- works, is to set the window.location.href to the url that I would like to the video to play, such as: 
https://Application:443/app/play/video?ID=1234

The url in turn renders an avi file (with the above content type), that is then downloaded to the users download directory, and it opens up the window media player to play the call. (i guess that is what the pc is set  up todo, when it  opens file of a certain type, it uses a prefered program to open the file up).

My concern is that I do not want the file to download, but rather that the browswer should try and play it from the online location.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance,
Harriet

Comment: The only possibility that comes to mind is if Windows Media Player registers a URI scheme, such as "wmplayer://Application:443/app/play", you could have people click on that. If not, getting a web browser to open an arbitrary program on your computer is a tough security-related feature and would probably not be allowed.

Comment: Hello @Katana314, thank you for your suggestion. I will investigate it, and see if it can work for me. The main issue is that this app deals with telephone calls that are recorded, so if the file is downloaded in order to listen to it, then it will crowd up the downloads folder pretty quickly, and will lead to space and storage management issues.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my suggestion. Research the term "URI schemes" and see if WMPlayer can access URLs directly from them - if so, it would use a temporary directory when accessing those files. If not, look into changing to the <audio> or <video> tag and a supported media format.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser doesn't support the format (and thus has to download it and open it in an external application) then it doesn't support the format.

So change the format to one that is supported.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a production system that currently is in use. In IE, you could specify the content type, and tell the web server that this is the content type you work with - and it would do the exact same as play it via external player. Which is fine, I just don't want it downloaded...